# Is a CAAnimation delegate guaranteed to be notified on the main thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-animation

Core animations run on their own threads. But is `animationDidStop:finished:` guaranteed to run on the main thread when the animation finishes? It does in my testing, but I don't know whether I can depend on that at all times and across all versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does occurs on the main thread as mentioned also in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455221/iphone-does-animation-stop-selector-run-on-the-main-thread). Starting iOS 4.0 and later consider using the `block-based animation methods` though.

**EDIT**

From the official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) for the description of the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` it is mentioned that the completion block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle. I believe we are talking about the loop cycle associated to the main thread here if you are invoking your method on the main thread.

Comment: That question only asserts that it does based on one trial. Is that guaranteed anywhere in documentation? Otherwise how do we know if it's reliable?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that yes, the `animationDidStop:finished:` method is always called on the main thread, but that's an understanding, not a guaranteed.

You might want to post this question to the Core Animation area in Apple's developer forum with a specific request that an Apple engineer weigh in. There are a number of Apple employees who post their regularly. (Rincewind comes to mind for Core Animation).